# Get users nickname in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine with a Google Account authentication. I have a list of Google e-mails, which have been used for authentication on my page. How can I get the user nickname/name for each of the e-mails? 
I can get it for current logged user by using User object, but I didn't find this option in Java for regular Google e-mail.

Python implementation has this functionality: `users.User(email)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User). There's a constructor for making a User object from an email address and authorization domain, from which you can get the nickname.

Take a look at @Andrei's answer bellow for an example (I actually don't code Java :) ).

Answer (score 2):

```
User user = new User(userEmail, "gmail.com");
String nickName = user.getNickName();
```